# OSError: file not found while generating input files for model

Tags: python, anaconda3

My goal is to generate input files for a Dispersal Extinction Sampling model following this [tutorial](https://github.com/dsilvestro/PyRate/blob/master/tutorials/pyrate_tutorial_5.md), but even when I put the files in the same folder as the script and use the absolute path it always ends up with a `OSError: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_recent.txt' not found.`

Anaconda prompt (anaconda3) ends up as this:

```
(base) C:\Users\User\Desktop\\PyRate>python .\PyRateDES.py -fossil 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_fossil.txt' -recent 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_recent.txt' -wd 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate' -filename Example -bin_size 0.5 -rep 10 -trim_age 23.03 -taxon accepted_name -area cc -age1 max_ma -age2 min_ma
Random seed:  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyRate\PyRateDES.py", line 189, in <module>
    desin_list, time = des_in(args.fossil, args.recent, args.wd, args.filename, taxon = args.taxon, area = args.area, age1 = args.age1, age2 = args.age2, binsize = args.bin_size, reps = reps, trim_age = args.trim_age, data_in_area = args.data_in_area)
  File "./pyrate_lib/lib_utilities.py", line 503, in des_in
    rece = np.genfromtxt(recent, dtype = str, delimiter='\t')
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1793, in genfromtxt
    fid = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 193, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 533, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_recent.txt' not found.
```

I checked to see if the files exist:

```
import glob

print(glob.glob('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\*.txt'))

runfile('C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3')
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\requirements.txt', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_fossil.txt', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_recent.txt']
```

What should I do to make this work? I'll try my best to share more info about the situation if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use double backslashes on your command line.

```
python .\PyRateDES.py -fossil C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyRate\example_fossil.txt -recent C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyRate\example_recent.txt -wd C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyRate -filename Example -bin_size 0.5 -rep 10 -trim_age 23.03 -taxon accepted_name -area cc -age1 max_ma -age2 min_ma
```

should do just fine (you don't need the quotes either, since your filenames don't have spaces in them).

You're seeing double backslashes in the `glob` output since that's how you'd escape a single backslash (if not using `r` strings) in Python. If you were to `print()` every item in that `glob` result, you'd see single backslashes (and no quotes either).

(The clue here is in

```
raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_recent.txt' not found.
```

– since the format specifier is `%s`, not `%r`, we can tell that the actual `path` actually has double slashes in it and quotes surrounding it. To wit:

```
>>> path = input()
'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_recent.txt'
>>> raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PyRate\\example_recent.txt' not found.
>>> raise IOError("%r not found." % path)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: "'C:\\\\Users\\\\User\\\\Desktop\\\\PyRate\\\\example_recent.txt'" not found.
>>>
```